# Creating PDF of a gdoc from a gsheet script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-docs

I have written a script within a gsheet that can create a gdoc based on the information in a row in the spreadsheet.

I am then trying to create a PDF of the gdoc that has been generated by the script in the gsheet.  I am trying to make this all one seamless function where the gdoc is created with the pertinent information and then a pdf is automatically created as well.  However, the PDF generated is always just a blank page.

I am able to add a script to a gdoc that will function correctly and create a pdf version of itself (or another gdoc), but when I run a function from a gsheet, it is always just the blank one-page pdf,  Does anybody know why this is happening, or have a solution?

Here is an example of one of the simpler scripts I've tried and works in the gdoc script - obviously when running it from the gsheet I have to know the ID first and then open the gdoc from that.

```
function convertPDF(docId)
{
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var docId = doc.getId();
  var docFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(docId).getParents().next().getId();
  var docblob = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getAs('application/pdf');
  docblob.setName(doc.getName() + ".pdf");
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(docblob);
  var fileId = file.getId();   
}
```

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: Are you using a replace method to replace keys on the Doc with information from the sheet? After you have finished writing all the values to the sheet are you calling the saveandclose()  function before creating the PDF?

Comment: Ahh thank you!  I wasn't saving and closing the Doc before trying to save it as a PDF (which would make sense why it was blank).